# Lua : Creating a class shows unusual behaviour with setAnchorPoint and serRotation

Tags: lua, gideros

I have this piece of code. In this example, If I replace 'Graphic' with 'self' at Graphic:setAnchorPoint and Graphic:setRotation, the image appears on screen but does not rotate. What is the reason?

I am fairly new to Gideros and do not totally understand the changes that needs to be made while I create a class.A short quick explanation is really required, Please?

I am using Lua with Gideros

```
WatchHands= Core.class(Sprite)
W, H = application:getDeviceWidth(), application:getDeviceHeight() 
H, W = W, H
ori = Application.LANDSCAPE_LEFT
application:setOrientation(ori)


function WatchHands:init(Image, posx, posy)
posx = posx or 0
posy = posy or 0
Graphic = Bitmap.new(Texture.new(Image))
Graphic: setAnchorPoint(0.2257, 0.5)
self:addChild(Graphic)
self: setPosition( posx, posy)
self.width = self: getWidth()
self.height = self: getHeight()
self: setScale(0.5, 1) 
Graphic:setRotation(math.random( 1,360))
self:addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, self.onAddedToStage, self)
return self
end

function WatchHands: playsound(sound)
local channel = sound:play()
return channel
end 
function WatchHands: onAddedToStage()
self:addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, 
   function()
       self:setRotation( Graphic:getRotation() + 5)
        Timer.delayedCall(math.random(30000, 60000), 
            function()
                self:setRotation( self:getRotation() + math.random(6,10) )
            end)
    end)
    end
sechand = WatchHands.new("secondshand.png", W/2, H/2)
minhand = WatchHands.new("minutehand.png", W/2, H/2)

 stage: addChild(sechand)
 stage: addChild(minhand)
```

Comment: Probably, second occurence of `Graphic` should also be replaced with `self` in `self:setRotation( Graphic:getRotation() + 5)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: That is okay, I made that change but the point is I want to now why does that work with Graphic:setRotation only and not self:setRotation ?

Answer (score 1):

In your case `Graphic` is an instance of `Bitmap` which you want to manipulate, while self is referencing to the instance of the class you are in, which in your case is `WatchHands`

If you rotate Graphic then only Graphic should rotate, but if you rotate WatchHands then all children of it including Graphic should rotate.

You can put a print in the ENTER_FRAME event like `print("Angle:", self:getRotation())` to see if the angle of self is actually increasing or you are having some other error in your code